# Apache flink: Dynamically change the consumer topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

We are building a flink application which will be deployed to AWS Kinesis data analytics(KDA). This application will consume from Kafka and write to S3.
Our setup is as follows:

1. We have a Kafka bootstrap server (MSK) with several topics.
2. We are planning to have multiple Flink applications deployed on KDA. All these applications will be part of the same consumer group.

We want to do the following:

1. Assume we have 10 kafka topics (`topic 1` through `topic 10`).
2. Assume we have 5 Flink application (`app 1` through `app 5`).
3. Initially we will assign applications to topics (ex: `app 1` will consume from `topic 1` and `2`, `app 2` will consume from `topic 3` and `4` and so on).
4. We will store this in a config system (say CRUD application) and each Flink app when it comes alive, should be able to see which topic it should consume from based on its name. (This part we are able to do).
5. Assume, suddenly there is a huge surge in the number of messages coming through `topic 4` for example. We will update the config system to point `App 4` which is consuming from `topic 7` and `topic 8` to instead consume from `topic 7` and `topic 4`.
6. We want the Flink app to stop consuming from the old topic and start consuming from the new topic without re-deploying the Flink app. We will have a poller which can inform the Flink app that it should consume from a different topic. The issue is making the Flink app stop consuming from the old topic and start consuming from the new topic without re-deployment.

Is there any way to do this? As far my research goes, the only way to make the Flink app to read from a new topic is to redeploy it. But want to check if there is some way some one has figured out.

Conversely: Will this situation be automatically handled if we make all the 5 Flink applications to listen to all the 10 topics? I mean, if there is a sudden surge in one of the topics, will the flink applications rebalance themselves to dedicate more resources to read from the hot topic since they are all part of the same consumer group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink's Kafka consumer does not support stopping consumption from a topic (without a restart), but it does support dynamic topic and partition discovery. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#dynamic-partition-discovery for details.

Comment: Sadly I have discovered that Flink Kafka consumer does not support removal of the topic nor scaling down as it keeps in its checkpoint list of every topic/partition that it ever was subscribed and in `org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator#handlePartitionSplitChanges` there is this `// TODO: Handle removed partitions.`.

So when you try to change topic name/scale down you will be getting lot of
`[] - [Consumer clientId=gr1-0, groupId=gr1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 59 : {test-1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`